# HTML/CSS style column

Tags: css, html, template

I need some help with my HTML email template. I am trying to copy this format: [image]

However, this is what the result I am getting: [image]

This is a PDF attachment and here's my code block for this section:

```html
<div class="body">
    
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" width= "0%">
    
    <!-- Invoice row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*****"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*****"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="{!$Label.fw1__Invoice_No}:"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!IF(Relatedto.fw1__Alternate_Invoice_Number__c != null,Relatedto.fw1__Alternate_Invoice_Number__c,Relatedto.Name)}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Account Id row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.Id != null}" value="Account ID: "/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.Id != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.Id}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*****"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*****"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Account Name row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.Name != null}" value="Account Name: "/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.Name != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.Name}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__PO_Number__c != null}" value="Client PO: "/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__PO_Number__c != null}" value="{!Relatedto.fw1__PO_Number__c}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <!-- Billing Address row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="{!$Label.fw1__Billing_Address}:"/>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*********************************"/>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*********************************"/>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*********************************"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Street__c == null}">
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingStreet != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingStreet}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingCity != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingCity}, "/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingState != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingState} "/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingPostalCode != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingPostalCode}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingCountry != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Account__r.BillingCountry}"/>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Street__c != null}">
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Street__c != null}" value="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Street__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_City__c != null}" value="{!Relatedto.Billing_City__c }, "/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_State__c != null}" value="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_State__c} "/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Zip__c != null}" value="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Zip__c}"/><br/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Country__c != null}" value="{!Relatedto.fw1__Billing_Country__c}"/>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <!-- Contact Name and CreatedDate row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Contact Name:" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Contact_Name__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.fw1__Contact_Name__c}" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw1__Contact_Name__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Created Date:"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputpanel styleClass="normalText">
                <c:outputTextFormatter type="date" locale="{!Relatedto.fw1__Locale__c}" value="{!TEXT(Relatedto.fw1__Invoice_Date__c)}">
                </c:outputTextFormatter>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Contact Email and MD Contract # row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Contact Email:" rendered="{!Relatedto.Contact__r.Email != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.Contact__r.Email}" rendered="{!Relatedto.Contact__r.Email != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="MD Contract #:" rendered="{!RelatedTo.fw2__Quote__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.fw2__Quote__c}" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Quote__c != null}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Contact Phone and MSF Opportunity ID # row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Contact Phone:" rendered="{!Relatedto.Contact__r.Phone != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.Contact__r.Phone}" rendered="{!Relatedto.Contact__r.Phone != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="MSF Opportunity ID #:" rendered="{!RelatedTo.fw2__Opportunity__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.MSF_Opportunity_ID__c}" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.MSF_Opportunity_ID__c != null}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Opportunity row -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Opportunity Information"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Opportunity Name:" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Name != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Name}" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Name != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Event Start Date:" rendered="{!RelatedTo.fw2__Opportunity__r.Event_Start_Date_Time__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputpanel styleClass="normalText">
                <c:outputTextFormatter type="date" locale="{!Relatedto.fw1__Locale__c}" value="{!TEXT(Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Event_Start_Date_Time__c)}">
                </c:outputTextFormatter>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Show Name:" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Show_Name__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Show_Name__c}" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Show_Name__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Event End Date:" rendered="{!RelatedTo.fw2__Opportunity__r.Event_End_Date_Time__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputpanel styleClass="normalText">
                <c:outputTextFormatter type="date" locale="{!Relatedto.fw1__Locale__c}" value="{!TEXT(Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Event_End_Date_Time__c)}">
                </c:outputTextFormatter>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="boldText" value="Related Venue:" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Venue__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText styleClass="normalText" value="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Venue__c}" rendered="{!Relatedto.fw2__Opportunity__r.Venue__c != null}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*********************************"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <apex:outputText style="color:white" value="*********************************"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

How to do format this so that the columns/width are align?

Thank you!